# How to setup ajaxFilter in DWR?

Tags: java, dwr

I create a DWR ajaxfilter, but not sure how to config it with Spring. DWR version is 2.0.1, and i hope config it as a globel filter, so when session is expired, i can catch this exception in client side.

package com.gbtags;

import org.directwebremoting.AjaxFilter;
import org.directwebremoting.AjaxFilterChain;
import org.directwebremoting.WebContextFactory;
import org.directwebremoting.extend.LoginRequiredException;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class DWRSessionFilter implements AjaxFilter {
    public Object doFilter(Object obj, Method method, Object[] params, AjaxFilterChain chain) throws Exception {

```
    //Check if session has timedout/invalidated
    if( WebContextFactory.get().getSession( false ) == null ) {
        System.out.println("session expired");
        //Throw an exception
        throw new LoginRequiredException( "This operation requires login." );

    }        

    return chain.doFilter(obj, method, params);
}
```

}

Comment: How can i configure it in dwr.xml?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add filter to dwr.xml as below:

Comment: where is the filter :|